# In visual Basic: AppConfig keeps giving a "System.NullReferenceException" (As simple a test as possible)

Tags: xml, windows, vb.net, runtime-error, app-config

I want to save some of my programs variables to a config.file.
So, I try to use "AppConfig ", as that almost seems to be the standard.
Before trying anything complicated, I put it to the test in a;
as simple as possible program. (and a variety of variations)
But I keep getting this error:System.NullReferenceException:
'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.'
(Visual Basic)(Visual Studio 2022) (Net.6)
In the line: `_settings.Settings.Item(propertyName).Value = propertyValue`
As per instruction I referenced :System.Configuration, And imported System.Configuration and System.Reflection
I try to save one variable "atest" and its data "bey".
So, why doesn't this work?
All the code:

```
Imports System.Configuration
Imports System.Reflection
Public Class Form1
    Sub New()
        Dim test As String = "bey"
        ' This call is required by the designer.
        InitializeComponent()
        Dim _appConfig As New AppConfig
        _appConfig.SetProperty("test", "dd")
    End Sub
End Class
Public Class AppConfig
    Private _config As Configuration
    Private _settings As AppSettingsSection

    Public Function GetProperty(propertyName As String) As String
        Return _settings.Settings.Item(propertyName).Value
    End Function

    Public Sub SetProperty(propertyName As String, propertyValue As String)
        _settings.Settings.Item(propertyName).Value = propertyValue
    End Sub

    Public Sub New()
        _config = ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration(Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().Location)
        _settings = _config.AppSettings
    End Sub

    Protected Overrides Sub Finalize()
        MyBase.Finalize()
        _config.Save(ConfigurationSaveMode.Modified)
    End Sub
End Class
```

Thanks in advance for any help...

I will probably feel very stupid if the solution is very simple...

P.S.
The code is almost literary all from this [Blog](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71895084/save-and-retrieve-application-and-user-settings)..

---

Update 1!

I did a U-turn as I found that there is an in-build function

that would be even more simple.

That resulted in more errors..

But eventually lead to half a [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71895084/save-and-retrieve-application-and-user-settings).

Please change channels to [that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71895084/save-and-retrieve-application-and-user-settings) thread, as this one seems to be redundant.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is a NullReferenceException, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: You seem to have left out most of the code of that `AppConfig` class but you haven't shown anywhere that you've actually assigned anything to the `_settings` field.

Comment: Yes, sorry... too long a night, not enough  coffee.